# Swift: sorting of array is not done correctly

Tags: arrays, sorting, swift

I am using this to sort components in an array in Swift:

```
myArray = myArray.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending }
```

However, it gives me the following result:

```
[18C, 18L, 18R, 22, 24, 27, 36C, 36L, 36R, 4, 6, 9]
```

Is it possible to sort it the right way, i.e.

```
[4, 6, 9, 18C, 18L, 18R, 22, 24, 27, 36C, 36L, 36R]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `compare` with `.NumericSearch`:

```
array.sortInPlace { $0.compare($1, options: .NumericSearch) == .OrderedAscending }
```

or

```
let array2 = array.sort { $0.compare($1, options: .NumericSearch) == .OrderedAscending }
```

Comment: In Swift 2 `sorted()` has been replaced by `sort()`.

Comment: This does not work if the entry begins with a String instead of a number.

Comment: @MountainMan: That is not true. Try it with the array `["file1.txt", "file10.txt", "file2.txt"]`.

Comment: Can you write an extension for using it esier?

Comment: Yes, you can, if you want.